# Unable to get saved SharedPreferences value in a class inside statice method

Tags: java, android

In my project I want to share my referral code with app link.I already save referral code in SharedPreferences but I am unable to set that message in a separate class.

```
public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static void shareMyApp(Context context) {

    String link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+context.getPackageName()+"Signup with my referral code.My Code is "+sharedPreferences.getString("member_id",null);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Via"));
}
```

This method is present inside a java class.When this method called an error appear.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

How Can I print that code with app link?

Comment: You don't initialize sharedPreferences, hence why it is null. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialized sharedPreferences?

something like

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void shareMyApp(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+context.getPackageName()+"Signup with my referral code.My Code is "+sharedPreferences.getString("member_id",null);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Via"));
}
```

Here, I:

- Move `sharedPreferences` to a local variable
- Initialize it, using the approach you outlined in the comments (you will need to add a static `import` for `PREF_NAME` or otherwise fix that bit up to refer to your existing `PREF_NAME` constant)
- Use `text/plain` instead of `text/*` (you are *sending* the content, so *you* specify what the MIME type is)

Comment: But get referral code as null

Comment: @ArpanSarkar: You may be using a different `SharedPreferences`, then. Somewhere else in your app, you are working with `SharedPreferences` to save data. There are lots of `SharedPreferences` objects, and I do not know what one you used. In my sample, I showed one common approach for getting a `SharedPreferences` object. As I wrote, you should replace `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` from my example with whatever code you are presently using to get your `SharedPreferences` object.

Comment: what SharedPreferences is  suitable for your answer

Comment: @ArpanSarkar: You are welcome to save your data to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. That is a common `SharedPreferences` for the entire app, and it is what preference screens use.

Comment: public MyAppPrefsManager(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

Comment: I use this SharedPreferences custom

Comment: @ArpanSarkar: That is fine. Replace `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` in my sample with `context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)` (though you will need to ensure that you can get access to the `PREF_NAME` constant).

Comment: please edit your answer in code.

Comment: also get same result.get referral code as null

Comment: @ArpanSarkar: Then I have no means of helping you further. As I have stated repeatedly, you need to use the same code for reading the `SharedPreferences` as you do for writing the `SharedPreferences`. You will need to do that yourself.

Comment: thanks for your response